# Does Vignette CMS serve HTML, CSS and JavaScript content gzipped?

Tags: http, gzip, vignette

I’m working on a project involving [Vignette](http://www.vignette.com/) as the CMS. Does anyone know if it serves HTML, CSS and JavaScript content gzipped?

(If anyone’s got an example of a site run on Vignette, that’d be great too, I could see if it’s doing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vignette does not do the job of a webserver. Once you publish content, you can configure the webserver (apache httpd, IIS etc.) to do the compression.